# Does science really have base for Its expriments?

Tags: experimental-physics, atomic-physics, models

For most of the macroscopic observations, everything has a reason, but going into the microscopic level, atoms, then the electrons, then quarks.

Science has proved the existence of quarks by various experiments, but no one has ever seen them, though, electron filming has been done but it is blurry.
Who knows that the thing we are assuming to be present today may not what it seems to be?

How can one conclude that conclusions of scientific experimental results (hypothesis) may always be correct?

Comment: Noboby say that they are always correct. All we can say is, that nobody has seen a counter example and the theory makes correct predictions.

Comment: For some reason scientists have bigger brains. They are not limited by the 5 senses they have and use reasoning and develop better tools to make accurate predictions. Although you have a point that some theories we develop may change and better ones may replace them... but the experiments we perform and the results we got will not.

Comment: You can prove things in mathematics, but not in science. Science is in the business of making theories that are consistent with our observations of the world. Experiments and new observations can increase (or decrease) our confidence in scientific theories, but they don't *prove* anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Things need not be seen to be real. Can one see gravity? "But gravity is a force. Matter must be seen. Right?" Wrong. "What it looks like?" may not be a well-defined question for everything that's our there. This is true for particles just as it's true for gravity.

Seeing is a subjective phenomenon that some living beings have evolved. We have evolved it to navigate the macroscopic word. So it makes sense that "what quantum mechanics looks like" is not a well-defined question. Nor is it an interesting question, because "seeing" is subjective and approximate.

By subjective, I mean different species may evolve different ways to see the universe. Humans paint colors and shapes in their heads in order to see. Maybe some aliens have evolved to navigate the universe in a fundamentally different way.

By approximate, I mean "seeing" only gives you the approximate information about what's out there. For instance, we used to believe that all particles have a well-defined position and momentum, because we could see that. But microscopic observations showed otherwise.

The truth about what's out there is best expressed in abstract mathematical equations. Humans arrive at those equations by using all sorts of observations, which includes seeing. We have not seen the quarks but we have observed its effects.

Answer (score 2):

This comes down to what you define as "real". One definition of real that I first heard from Sabine Hossenfelder is that real could be any necessary ingredient in your model.

So if there's something you can't see, but you have a model which seems to be able to predict a bunch of visible outputs based on inputs, then the necessary moving bits and pieces in that model could be considered to be real. So if your model which seems to be really accurate and is as simple as you can make it without losing that accuracy needs protons, electrons, and neutrons as moving pieces in its inner workings and equations then those could be considered to be real.

The problem is when you have two different models that mostly give the same predictions but disagree in some small cases. Even worse is when you do experiments and both predictions appear to be true! They can't both be right. The famous one being particle-wave duality. You have to then dig into that discrepancy to come up with a deeper, more accurate model that explains everything.